# Extra Gap in UINavigationItem with Personal Hotspot

Tags: ios

I am facing a weird problem and I have no idea how to solve this. I turn on personal hotspot and turn on my app and go to a specific view. After I click on some UITextField or UITextView (it shows keyboard), UINavigationItem is pushed down with some extra gap. This only happens when Personal Hotspot is turned on.

Below you can see an image of that gap. I am wondering how to solve this issue.

Before:
[image]

After
[image: Gap is just below the Personal Hotspot Text]

Comment: Can you provide any related code?

Comment: Use the view debugger to check the position of the various views and the values of the relevant constraints. This should help pinpoint which views are incorrectly placed and/or which constraints have incorrect values.

Comment: Its not related to code I think. There is almost no code. Also it only happens when uitextfield is touched and after keypad appears.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement,

```
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

in your `viewDidLoad` and it may help!!!

Second thing it's depends on autolayout also, your constraints for the root view or super is is like `top,bottom,leading and trailing` with `superview`.

**Update :**

try,

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```